# вывод с mysql и подсчёт

Tags: php, mysql

есть таблица `prefix_wall`

```
----------id                 1    2   3   4    5    6    7    9
----------wall_user_id       10   11  10  9    9  16    16   10
----------user_id            12   22  33  32   33  44    22   434
```

`wall_user_id`  - id стена пользователя
`user_id`  - id пользователя кто оставлял сообщение

```
вторая таблица  'prefix_user'
    ----------user_id                    1                2              5
    ----------user_profile_name        Иванов          Петров          Саутин
```

Как сделать такой вывод, чтобы он выводил так:

Брал `wall_user_id` и считал сколько одинаковых записей в  нем и выводил кол-во

```
wall_user_id  | кол-во записей которые повторяются
      10      |    3
      11      |    1  
      9       |    2  
      16      |    2
```

```php
//ВЫВОД 
if(!isset($_GET['wall_user_id'])) { 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT wall_user_id, wall_user_id,  COUNT( wall_user_id) AS wall_user_id FROM prefix_wall GROUP BY wall_user_id");
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    do {
        echo "<b>".$myrow['wall_user_id']."-<br>" ; 
    } while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
}
//ВЫВОД
```

Comment: А  `COUNT` отменили чтоли в `mysql`? Вы что-то пробовали написать?

Comment: да $result = mysql_query("SELECT wall_user_id,  COUNT(*)  FROM prefix_wall GROUP BY wall_user_id"); Но он выводит только 10 -11-9-16 а кол-во их не выводит

Comment: это не "он количества не выводит", а вы это количество не выводите, сделайте `count(*) as cnt` и выводите количество через cnt так же, как вы и wall_user_id  выводите

Comment: так выводит кол-во SELECT wall_user_id, COUNT( wall_user_id) AS wall_user_id FROM prefix_wall GROUP BY wall_user_id"  но без id, а как еще сделать чтобы id и кол-во вместе было

Comment: @ZOymyng, добавьте свой PHP код в тело вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Очень просто. Комментарии, думаю, не нужны

```
SELECT wall_user_id, COUNT(wall_user_id) FROM prefix_wall GROUP BY wall_user_id
```

#### UPDATE

(после редактирования вопроса)

[В офф. документации](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) есть пример относительно этого момента.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT wall_user_id, COUNT(wall_user_id) FROM prefix_wall GROUP BY wall_user_id");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("wall_user_id: %s  Count: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
}
```

И да, используйте PDO. Ваш способ устарел и не является безопасным.

Comment: После редактирования вопроса ТС, ваш ответ больше не имеет смысла. Увы.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, отредактировал.

Comment: спс, получилось.   такой вопрос,
wall_user_id = id_user

есть вторая таблица prefix_user где
a id_user и name_user

как вывести вместо wall_user_id -> name_user

Подскажите

Comment: знаю что надо использовать JOIN , но пока не вьеду как

Comment: @ZOymyng, я вам рекомендую почитать об SQL JOIN-ах. Погуглите: SQL JOIN examples. Или : SQL JOIN примеры.

Comment: подскажите что тут не так?   $result = mysql_query("SELECT wall_user_id, user_profile_name, user_id COUNT(wall_user_id) 
FROM prefix_wall 
INNER JOIN prefix_user
ON prefix_wall.wall_user_id=prefix_user.user_profile_name
GROUP BY wall_user_id  wall_user_id.user_profile_name");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("Пользователи %s - Очки: %s", $row[0], $row[1]."<br>" );  
}

Comment: @ZOymyng, нельзя сказать, не увидев структуры таблиц.

Comment: в топике накидал структура 2-ух таблиц

Comment: @ZOymyng, с ходу только такая замена: `ON prefix_wall.wall_user_id=prefix_user.user_id`. "Что тут не так?" не является форматом вопросов Stack Overflow. Ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста, с рекомендациями о том [На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем вот решение задачи

```
SELECT pu.user_profile_name, COUNT(pw.wall_user_id) as cnt
FROM prefix_wall AS pw
LEFT JOIN prefix_user AS pu ON (pu.user_id = pw.wall_user_id)
GROUP BY pw.wall_user_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```